Can I create a custom client/customer end dashboard in squarespace?
So basically I am designing this website and want to deal with clients using forms submissions which I can see I can do that by create projects and invoicing from the squarespace dashboard. Send proposals and stuff like many options for me and the admin accounts but the problem is clients/customers account where there are not many options like he/she cant see the number of form submissions they did, the proposals sent to them by admins or look at the status for those proposals, invoices, previous orders submitted or rejected etc. So how can i make a proper dashboard for my clients as well to come and see all the details of services, orders, forms, proposals, previous orders etc. Currently there are only address, order option available and the order will work if I create a products page or service only can you please guide me through if there are any options where I can create a custom account dashboard for my clients as well?
So like as a owner/admin I dont want to make a store as I want to sell my services through form submissions and stuff. Squarespace provides many options for admins but not much for customers account.
There are some options to make it custom like zapier and airtable integration with square space and I think its not that simple and requires alot of work. And the other option is custom dashboard in Django.
I hope I have conveyed my message properly, thanks for reading.
